# highcharts polar chart add max tick mark

Tags: highcharts

If you have a look at this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/m14ufsmy/5/), you'll see I have:

```
tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But only ticks 0 - 4 show up. How do I get the max tick "5" to show up?
And can I hide the "0", without it messing up the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [yAxis.showLastLabel](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showLastLabel)  and [yAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter)

You have to update yAxis as

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  showLastLabel: true, //displays last label
  labels: {
    y: 15,    //displays labels below ring
    formatter: function() {
      console.log(this.value)
      var value = this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
      return (this.value === 0 ? ' ' : value);  //hides 0 value
    }
  }
},
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e08xp436/) demo

Comment: Wow, how did I miss the "showLastLabel". I know I read through the API docs. Thanks, very much.